# Add values to database on button click

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello I made a code to enter the values from the input text into the databse but it add an empty values in the database

```
   <html>
<body>
<input type="text" name="value" />
<input type="text" name="value2" />
<input type="text" name="value3" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Register</button>
<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "root";
$password = "ahmed2001";
$db = "html";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);
if(!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
<script>
function myFunction() {
<?php
$user = $_POST['value'];
$pass = $_POST['value2'];
$em = $_POST['value3'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO players (username, password, email)
VALUES ('$value', '$value2', '$value3')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created succeddfully !";
} else {
    echo "Error : " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there anyway to do it without usin jQuery ?

Comment: Your code contains your root password. Plus, it’s prone to SQL injections.

Comment: That's because you're referencing the wrong variables. Here, visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and use that. It will throw you the errors. You also don't have form tags with a post method. JS functions do NOT call PHP functions.

Comment: Your `myFunction` is going to contain invalid javascript because you're echoing plain text out from PHP. You probably need to split the PHP into a separate script and cal it asynchronously when the register button is clicked.

Comment: Code makes no sense , why are you wrapping db query code inside a javascript function . PHP and javascript run in different environments and at different times. You are unknowingly creating an empty insert every time the page loads

Comment: Elsewhere you are having trouble with this SQL string: `$sql = "INSERT INTO players (username, password, email)
VALUES ($_POST['name'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['email'])";`. You will find it will work if you put braces around your arrays, thus: `{$_POST['name']}`. However, **don't use it!** - as this code is unsafe. As others have pointed out, it contains a SQL injection, which may well get you hacked.

Answer (score 4):

You're mixing server-side code and client-side code.  A lot.

Server-side code (PHP in this case) executes on the server when the page is requested.  It executes in its entirety, and then displays the page.  This is your server-side code:

```
$servername = "";
$username = "root";
$password = "ahmed2001";
$db = "html";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);
if(!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$user = $_POST['value'];
$pass = $_POST['value2'];
$em = $_POST['value3'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO players (username, password, email)
VALUES ('$value', '$value2', '$value3')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created succeddfully !";
} else {
    echo "Error : " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

When the page first loads, there are no `$_POST` values.  (And even if there were, you're not using those values in your SQL query.  You're using variables that were never defined.)  So you're just inserting empty strings into your database.  (Also note that this code has a [SQL injection vulnerability](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).  You'll want to read up on that.)

Then, after this code has executed, the page is rendered in the browser and the client-side code executes.  This is your client-side code:

```
function myFunction() {
    New record created succeddfully !
}
```

For one thing, this isn't valid JavaScript code.  For another thing, this function doesn't do anything.  You're undoubtedly getting an error in your browser's console, so you should take a look at that.  But even if you remove that line of non-code, you still just have an empty function.  You can call that function all you like, it won't do anything.

You're going to want to start with some introductory tutorials on PHP, to be honest.  Basically, in order for the client-side code to send values to the server-side code, those values need to be posted to the server in a request of some kind.  It can be a `form` post, or maybe an AJAX request, or possibly something else.  But you can't mix the server-side code and the client-side code.

Comment: OP seems to be using the HTML form and PHP/MySQL inside the same page. If that is the case, then that will throw undefined index(es) notices. Best to use `isset()` or `empty()` on the POST arrays.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Agreed.  Personally I like to separate the two, but I realize it's not uncommon to have the form and the form handler in the same PHP file.  Though there's a lot more wrong with the OP's code.  (There's no actual form, for example.)  An introductory tutorial on PHP would really be his best bet here.  The scope of one Stack Overflow question just won't cut it :)

Comment: *So true* David, I agree using seperate files.